# Add custom key/value to JWT token payload or user with keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, openid, keycloak

I have keycloak running in localhost. 
I want to

- add a key/value pair to the token payload
- or add a key/value pair related to the user (payload again)

Can you suggest me a way to do this and a way to verify that it has been added?

(I guess with https://jwt.io/)

Comment: A key/value pair ? What do you mean ? You want to add some payload in the claims of the JWT ? Only the keycloak server can add custom payload, if you do it outside, the signature will become invalid. To add custom claims check this https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/content/server_admin/topics/clients/protocol-mappers.html

Comment: Yes, I want to add a key/value pair to the payload of the token, exactly, I am the administrator of the keycloak server so I can do that.

Comment: Okay, then the solution is explained in the link of my previous comment.

Comment: I tried to add a key/value pair in the mappers sections as user attribute and user property. When I copy paste the access token in _jwt.io_ to verify its payload, I do not see my custom key/value pairs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned above by Sébastien, a mapper should be added. So I have added a mapper *user attribute* and then I went to *users->attributes* and added the same key name with its value. I verified it afterwards, the key/value pair is included in the payload

Comment: The doc link in the comment is dead. Is there a current doc/ article about the solution?

Comment: what if i want to add list of strings in  one key